# Hazelcast: difference between Java native client and embedded version

Tags: hazelcast

We use Hazelcast (2.3) in a Web backend running in a Java servlet container to distribute data in a cluster. Hazelcast maps are persisted in a MySQL database using a MapStore interface. Right now, we are using the Java native client interface and I wonder what is the difference between a "native" client and the embedded version when it comes to performance.

1. Is it correct that a "native" client might connect to any of the cluster nodes and that this decision is made again for every single request?
2. Is it correct that the overhead of sending all requests and responses through a TCP socket in a native client is avoided when the embedded version is used?
3. Is it fair to conclude that the embedded version is in general faster than the "native" client?
4. In case of a "native" client: it is correct that the MapStore implementation is part of the Hazelcast server (as class during runtime)? Or is it part of the "native" client so that all data that has to be persisted is sent through the TCP socket at first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You give the set of nodes for native client to connect. Once it connects one it will use this node for communication with cluster till it dies. When it dies client will connect to other node to continue communication.
2. With native client there are two hops one from client to the node, one from the node to target node. (Target node is the node the target data is located) With embedded client there is single hop as it already knows where the wanted data is located (target node)
3. Yes generally but see: (from [hazelcast documentation](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.4/manual/single_html/#NativeClient))

> LiteMember is a member of the cluster, it has socket connection to
>   every member in the cluster and it knows where the data is so it will
>   get to the data much faster. But LiteMember has the clustering
>   overhead and it must be on the same data center even on the same RAC.
>   However Native client is not member and relies on one of the cluster
>   members. Native Clients can be anywhere in the LAN or WAN. It scales
>   much better and overhead is quite less. So if your clients are less
>   than Hazelcast nodes then LiteMember can be an option; otherwise
>   definitely try Native Client. As a rule of thumb: Try Native client
>   first, if it doesn't perform well enough for you, then consider
>   LiteMember.

4- Store operations are executed in hazelcast server. The object sent from client is persisted to centralized datastore by the target node which also stores the object in its memory.